# Kivy fails to run a basic window

Tags: python, user-interface, pycharm, kivy

I'm trying to run this code :

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text ="Hello World")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

but I get the error below all the time, i tried to re-install Kivy and Python...

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\gabi\.kivy\logs\kivy_21-12-22_45.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\gabi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.9:ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\gabi\PycharmProjects\kivy_1\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pil (img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _window_sdl2: The specified module could not be found.
  File "C:\Users\gabi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 58, in core_select_lib
    mod = __import__(name='{2}.{0}.{1}'.format(
  File "C:\Users\gabi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm running python 3.9.9 with PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

One of my friends have same problem it's very easy to solve, in windows just run cmd and type the following commnands to completely delete kivy:

```
pip uninstall Kivy kivy.deps.angle kivy.deps.glew kivy.deps.sdl2
```

then type `pip freeze` and check if there still any packages start with kivy delete it using `pip uninstall [package-name]`
then run cmd **as administrator** and type the following command:

```
pip install kivy[base]
```